# Can't open file even though it exists at the given directory

Tags: java, file-io

```
    import java.io.*;


    File thisun = new File("C:\\Users\\CH\\Documents\\dictionary.txt");
    System.out.println(thisun.canRead());
```

for some reason it can't read this file even though it does exist at the given directory : / I'm sure it's something very simple, but it just won't see it. I've even tried doing it from different directories.

Also, what if I just want to open a file in the same folder as say my .java file. I know in C++ it defaults to wherever my .cpp file is located but I don't know what the equivalent is for java.

Comment: What error or exception messages are you seeing?

Comment: Can you post the result of doing `System.out.println(thisun.list());` ? Change  your file to point to `C:\\Users\\CH\\Documents`.

Comment: [Ljava.lang.String;@659e0bfd

changed the directory to what you said.

Comment: Do `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(thisun.list()));`

Comment: *"I know in C++ it defaults to wherever my .cpp file is located"* Nope.

Comment: Please remove the C++ tag, no reason at all to have it.

Comment: I figured it out. It was one of two things: when I created the file I added the .txt extension, which I guess is implied on windows 8 or something. Further, I had properties of the file open while trying to open it with java, which I'm guessing the OS masked it from access for safety reasons. Or maybe it was leprechauns. Who knows, really. It works, now, though.

Comment: @BaummitAugen then where does it default to? That's what it seemed like. Sorry, this is getting really off topic. Oh, and sorry for the c++ tag. It was from a previous post I was gonna make before I figured out what was happening.

Comment: @MadisonC.Brewer It defaults to the path your executable is in. (Usually)

Comment: Lol, makes more sense. I made the wrong assumption because I've only tested and built in the same file.

Comment: Sounds like it's solved, but was going to suggest checking for existance once the File object was instantiated.